# What are the differences between #version 330 and #version 330 core?

Tags: opengl, glsl

What are the differences between `#version 330` and `#version 330 core` ?

Does the `core` matter?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those two version declarations are equivalent. `core` is the default. From the GLSL 3.30 spec:

> If no profile argument is provided, the default is core.

Which means that:

```
#version 330
```

is the same as:

```
#version 330 core
```

If you want to use the compatibility profile, you need to specify that explicitly with:

```
#version 330 compatibility
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reading this:
https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Core_And_Compatibility_in_Contexts